# MFC application (.exe) is not opening on another computer which has processor architecture wow64

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have created one mfc application which is created using visual studio 2005 (vc++) on windows xp service pack3 operating system. application exe is opening on my computer correctly but,

It is not opening on another machine having operation system windows 7 service pack 1 with 64 bit architecture.

Error: This application is failed to start because its side by side  configuration is incorrect.

to solve this error, I have installed many redistributable packages on that computer like VS2005(x86 & x64), VS2008(x86 & x64), VS2010, VS2013 etc. but same error persist.

I have run sxstracer.exe and log file is generated to see side by side error.

I found problem of processor architecture wow64

log file as below:

> Begin Activation Context Generation.
>
> Input Parameter: Flags = 0
>
> ProcessorArchitecture = Wow32
>
> CultureFallBacks = en-US;en
>
> ManifestPath = C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\tracer\setup_tracer_application\Tracer_Utility.exe
>
> AssemblyDirectory = C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\tracer\setup_tracer_application\
>
> Application Config File =
>
> INFO: Parsing Manifest File C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\tracer\setup_tracer_application\Tracer_Utility.exe.
>
> INFO: Manifest Definition Identity is (null).
>
> INFO: Reference:
>   Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.762"
>
> INFO: Reference:
>   Microsoft.VC80.MFC,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.762"
>
> INFO: Reference:
>   Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls,language="*",processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df",type="win32",version="6.0.0.0"
>
> INFO: Resolving reference
>   Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.762".
>
> INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
>
> INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
>
> INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
>
> INFO: No publisher policy found.
>
> INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
>
> INFO: Begin assembly probing.
>
> INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
>
> INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at 
>   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.CRT\8.0.50727.762__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.DLL.
>
> INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
>
> INFO: End assembly probing.
>
> INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
>
> INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
>
> INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
>
> INFO: Find publisher policy at 
>   C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_policy.8.0.microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4940_none_516d712b0f495a45.manifest
>
> INFO: Publisher Policy redirected assembly version.
>
> INFO: Post policy assembly identity is
>   Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.4940".
>
> INFO: Begin assembly probing. INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at
>   C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4940_none_d08cc06a442b34fc.manifest.
>
> INFO: Manifest found at
>   C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4940_none_d08cc06a442b34fc.manifest.
>
> INFO: End assembly probing. INFO: Resolving reference
>   Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui,language="*",processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.4940".
>
> INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
>
> INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
>
> INFO: Applying Binding Policy. INFO: No publisher policy found.
>
> INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
>
> INFO: Begin assembly probing. INFO: Did not find the assembly in
>   WinSxS.
>
> INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at
>   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui\8.0.50727.4940_en-US_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui.DLL.
>
> INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
>
> INFO: End assembly probing.
>
> INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
>
> INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
>
> INFO: No publisher policy found.
>
> INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
>
> INFO: Begin assembly probing.
>
> INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
>
> INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at
>   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui\8.0.50727.4940_en_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui.DLL.
>
> INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
>
> INFO: End assembly probing.
>
> INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
>
> INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.
>
> INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
>
> INFO: No publisher policy found.
>
> INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
>
> INFO: Begin assembly probing. INFO: Did not find the assembly in
>   WinSxS.
>
> INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at
>   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui\8.0.50727.4940_en-US_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui.DLL.
>
> INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.
>
> INFO: End assembly probing. INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.
>
> INFO: Applying Binding Policy. INFO: No publisher policy found.
>
> INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
>
> INFO: Begin assembly probing.
>
> INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
>
> INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at
>   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui\8.0.50727.4940_en_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.mui.DLL.
>
> INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.
>
> INFO: End assembly probing.
>
> INFO: Resolving reference
>   Microsoft.VC80.MFC,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.762".
>
> INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
>
> INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
>
> INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
>
> INFO: No publisher policy found.
>
> INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
>
> INFO: Begin assembly probing. INFO: Did not find the assembly in
>   WinSxS.
>
> INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at
>   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.MFC\8.0.50727.762__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.MFC.DLL.
>
> INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
>
> INFO: End assembly probing.
>
> INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
>
> INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral. INFO: Applying Binding
>   Policy.
>
> INFO: Find publisher policy at 
>   C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_policy.8.0.microsoft.vc80.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.42_none_54c11df268b7c6d9.manifest
>
> INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
>
> INFO: Begin assembly probing.
>
> INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
>
> INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at 
>   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC80.MFC\8.0.50727.762__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC80.MFC.DLL.
>
> INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\tracer\setup_tracer_application\Microsoft.VC80.MFC.DLL.
>
> INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\tracer\setup_tracer_application\Microsoft.VC80.MFC.MANIFEST.
>
> INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\tracer\setup_tracer_application\Microsoft.VC80.MFC\Microsoft.VC80.MFC.DLL.
>   INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\tracer\setup_tracer_application\Microsoft.VC80.MFC\Microsoft.VC80.MFC.MANIFEST.
>
> INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
>
> INFO: End assembly probing.
>
> ERROR: Cannot resolve reference
>   Microsoft.VC80.MFC,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.762".
>
> ERROR: Activation Context generation failed.
>
> End Activation Context Generation.

---

whatever I have done is written as above and not getting solution
So, Can any one suggest me solution for above error by looking in log file ?

Comment: how did you build the project? "dynamic dll" or "static"?

Comment: I am using mfc in shared dll configuration

Comment: Application Run on windows xp service pack 3 environment (not installed visual studio software tool) by installing vs2005 sp1 redestributed package (x86) . But not working on windows 7 sp1 and windows 8.1 environment .

Comment: try a project built with static dll

Comment: by using static dll configuration, it gives error: application is unable to start correctly (0xc0150002). I am using external dll files also in my application.

Comment: Have you tried using depends - http://www.dependencywalker.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a more modern compiler such as VS2013 or 2015 community edition that still allows you to target windows XP